# why the CoordinatorLayout show white space in the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, coordinator-layout

HI I have main activity XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="@color/fcolor"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="@color/scolor" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

As you can see I add my main content inside the CoordinatorLayout using Include Tag

```
  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

in content main XML, I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/actvity_main" tools:context=".Main">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

then I used different XML layout have Mapview within RelativeLayout to show in the page viewer

my problem that always there's empty space in the bottom of the screen left from the CoordinatorLayout as the below image

[image]

As you can see there's white space in the bottom, the reason why I know it's from CoordinatorLayout because when I change the CoordinatorLayout background it changes the space color

it seems like my include tag not scale in hight for all the screen, even when I set

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

still the same, **what I need is to make my Mapview scale and fill the bottom of the screen**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.xml`, remove `android:paddingBottom="3dp"`.

Comment: try it still the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

try in your java code

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
int level = mapView.getZoomLevel();
MapController mc = mapView.getController();
mc.setZoom(level + 3);
```

and your xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: try it still the same

Comment: thanks for help look like I was adding padding inside my code

Answer (score 0):

look like the problem was that I adding padding value inside the java code 
Thanks for everyone help me to review the padding inside my code

Answer (score 0):

In content main try removing from the RelativeLayout:

`android:paddingBottom="3dp"`

From the ViewPager, moving:
`android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"`
to the
`<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`

and in the ViewPager, changing:

`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
to
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`